# Как разбить массив numpy на рандомные выборки

Tags: python, numpy

К примеру есть массив:

```
X = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14])
```

Нужно его разбить на `n` выборок при чем рандомных, к примеру если разбить на 2 выглядеть будет как то так:

```
[[11, 2, 7, 10, 14, 1, 3], [12, 5, 9, 4, 6, 8, 13]]
```

Можно конечно перемешать массив и использовать `reshape()` но здесь вылезла проблема, к примеру если в массиве 14 чисел и я хочу разбить этот массив на 5 выборок то `reshape()` понятное дело уже не поможет:

```
X.reshape(5,4)
# ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 14 into shape (5,4)
```

Результат должен быть таким:

```
[[11, 10, 13], [3, 12,  6], [1, 7, 9], [8, 14,  5], [4, 2]]
```

Для решения этой проблемы написал не короткую функцию, где X - массив с данными, n - число выборок на которые нужно этот массив разбить:

```
def samples(X, n):
    data = np.random.permutation(X)
    step = round(X.shape[0] / n)
    return np.array([data[i:i+step] for i in range(0, len(X), step)])
```

Уверен что решить это можно куда короче без использования генератора, методами numpy, подскажите как это сделать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [`np.array_split()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html):

```
In [30]: np.array_split(X, 5)
Out[30]:
[array([1, 2, 3]),
 array([4, 5, 6]),
 array([7, 8, 9]),
 array([10, 11, 12]),
 array([13, 14])]

In [31]: np.array_split(X, 4)
Out[31]:
[array([1, 2, 3, 4]),
 array([5, 6, 7, 8]),
 array([ 9, 10, 11]),
 array([12, 13, 14])]

In [32]: np.array_split(X, 3)
Out[32]: [array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), array([ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10]), array([11, 12, 13, 14])]
```

---

Для задач связанных с машинным обучением часто используется функция [sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html), которая "тасует" случайным образом и разбивает набор входных (`X`) и выходных/предсказываемых (`y`) данных на тренировочный и тестируемый сеты `X_train`, `X_test`, `y_train`, `y_test`:

Пример:

```
In [38]: from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

In [39]: X = np.random.randint(10, size=(6, 3))

In [40]: y = np.random.randint(10, size=(6))

In [41]: X
Out[41]:
array([[9, 7, 6],
       [9, 2, 7],
       [4, 0, 5],
       [6, 3, 3],
       [3, 9, 9],
       [3, 3, 7]])

In [42]: y
Out[42]: array([6, 4, 8, 0, 8, 1])

In [43]: X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33)

In [44]: X_train
Out[44]:
array([[4, 0, 5],
       [3, 3, 7],
       [3, 9, 9],
       [9, 2, 7]])

In [45]: X_test
Out[45]:
array([[9, 7, 6],
       [6, 3, 3]])

In [46]: y_train
Out[46]: array([8, 1, 8, 4])

In [47]: y_test
Out[47]: array([6, 0])
```

Comment: Спасибо, я как чувствовал )