# Тестовая и обучающая выборка

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, машинное-обучение

Как задать матрицу `Y_train` и `Y_test`? И как избавиться от `NaN`?

```
churn_result = churn_df['TRG_is_churn']
churn_result
y = np.where(churn_result == 'True.',1,0)
```

Выдает ошибку:

> TypeError: invalid type comparison

Comment: Приведите небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример данных в вопросе. Советую ознакомиться: ["Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL / etc.?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060)

Comment: [связанный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/797743/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-numpy-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8)

Comment: churn_result = data['TRG_is_churn']
churn_result_clean = [x for x in churn_result if str(x) != 'nan']
y = np.where(churn_result_clean == 'True.',1,0)

Comment: В целом, вот так работает! Отчистила вектор ответов от NaN!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Имея следующий DataFrame:

```
In [71]: df
Out[71]:
  TRG_is_churn
0        True.
1       False.
2          NaN
3     Nonsense
4          NaN
5         None
6          NaN
7          NaN
8        True.

In [72]: df['TRG_is_churn'].isna()
Out[72]:
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
5    False
6     True
7     True
8    False
Name: TRG_is_churn, dtype: bool
```

сравнение с `'True.'` вернет булевую серию (Series)

```
In [73]: df['TRG_is_churn'] == 'True.'
Out[73]:
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
6    False
7    False
8     True
Name: TRG_is_churn, dtype: bool
```

которую можно преобразовать в целое:

```
In [74]: y = (df['TRG_is_churn'] == 'True.').astype(np.int8)

In [75]: y
Out[75]:
0    1
1    0
2    0
3    0
4    0
5    0
6    0
7    0
8    1
Name: TRG_is_churn, dtype: int8
```

тоже самое в виде Numpy array:

```
In [76]: y = (df['TRG_is_churn'] == 'True.').astype(np.int8).values

In [77]: y
Out[77]: array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], dtype=int8)
```

PS старайтесь избегать циклов при работе с Pandas/Numpy/Scipy/sklearn/etc.

Comment: ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer

Comment: Спасибо! Но если у меня в векторе ответов не только NaN ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer.

Comment: @АленаГайбатова, попробуйте привести в вопросе небольшой __воспроизводимый__ пример данных. В моем тестовом примере - все работает правильно...